# Is it possible to use a semi colon within a list?

Tags: lists, semicolons

I have seen questions looking at using semi-colons to make a list, but I am looking to ask whether semi-colons can go within lists to better define the objects in the list. I am looking to write a list within a sentence like this:

> These genes are significant in related conditions (*gene1; kidney disease, gene2; cardiac arrhythmia, gene3; arterial stiffness, gene4; aortic aneurysm*) suggesting new avenues of work.'

I am not great with grammar, so I am not sure if this is actually correct to do; apologies if I am missing an important rule.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is acceptable to use semi-colons in a list. However, the semi-colon is a stronger separator than a comma, so your example is effectively making a list which separates the items like this (which doesn't make sense):

```
gene1
kidney disease, gene2
cardiac arrhythmia, gene3
arterial stiffness, gene4
aortic aneurysm
```

It would be better to swap the commas and semi-colons:

> 'These genes are significant in related conditions (gene1, kidney
>   disease; gene2,  cardiac arrhythmia; gene3, arterial stiffness; gene4,
>   aortic aneurysm) suggesting new avenues of work.'

Alternatively you could replace the commas with dashes:

> 'These genes are significant in related conditions (gene1 - kidney
>   disease; gene2 - cardiac arrhythmia; gene3 - arterial stiffness; gene4
>   - aortic aneurysm) suggesting new avenues of work.'

Comment: I would think colons might also work: _gene1: kidney disease; gene2: cardiac arrhythmia; gene3: arterial stiffness..._. However, looking at it now, the colon might be too visually similar to the comma. So the dash might be the best way to go.

Comment: In the revised version, you could also replace the commas with colons. Also note that if you *do* replace the commas, there is no reason why the existing semicolons couldn't *become* commas. You normally only use a semicolon in this case if one or more list items already contain a comma.

Comment: Thank you for this and the above comments, this is much clearer to me now!